# JQuery Click event didnt respond

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little issue with a JQuery event. I'd like too load a HTML page in a div on a button click . Button's are created dynamically with an xslt for each and the scritp too.
In the browser all is well interpreted, but the event didn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 console.log('partie1');
  $('#Btn_MILENG').click(function(){
   console.log('partie2');
   $( "#DIV_DETAIL" ).html('<object data="SomeURL"></object>' );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" role="submit" name="Btn_MILENG">Détails</a>
```

If someone see's the problem, it would be very helpfull for me.

Comment: just give id to <a> element.

Comment: without giving id how can you call the click() event. assign id and then check.

Answer (score 3):

your `link` dont have an `Id`

Either add an `Id="Btn_MILENG"` to your `link`, or change `$('#Btn_MILENG')` ==> `$('[name="Btn_MILENG"]')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('partie1');
  $('#Btn_MILENG').click(function() {
    console.log('partie2');
    $("#DIV_DETAIL").html('<object data="SomeURL"></object>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" role="submit" id="Btn_MILENG" name="Btn_MILENG">Détails</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just dont given Id to  element

change your line to

`<a id="Btn_MILENG" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" role="submit" name="Btn_MILENG">Détails</a>`

Comment: i have already tried with the id but it didn't work. is it important that le <a> stand in a table ?

Comment: what didn't work exactly?it should work after adding id to <a>.But <a> tag should be in DOM

Comment: The a tag Id was one of my try , i'm on this since a few hours now and that why i ask for help :) Here i'd just try all the solution given but in Chrome , i see the first console log ( on document ready) but the second who fire on click didn't appear. I'm totally lost ^^

Comment: Actually I am not getting what exactly you are trying to explain.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is not working and what you want to achieve.

Comment: With an XSLT transformation, i dynamically create an UL/LI list.
This list is for a orgchart ( i use this [link](https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart ) ) and in the orgchart i made a button who on click call a detailled datatable . here is a printscreen [link](http://hpics.li/c6d187d) . 
Hope this is can help you helping me :) 
PS: all is dynamically created ;)

Comment: after you dynamically added element execute $('#Btn_MILENG').click(function() {
    console.log('partie2');
    $("#DIV_DETAIL").html('<object data="SomeURL"></object>');
  }); code so it will bind click event

Comment: can you show how you are binding element dynamically?

Comment: Look behind , i post the code , in another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add id tag

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs Btn_MILENG" href="#" role="submit"  id="Btn_MILENG">Détails</a>
```

or you can use class

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
console.log('partie1');
    $('.Btn_MILENG').click(function(){
    console.log('partie2');
           $( "#DIV_DETAIL" ).html('<object data="SomeURL"></object>' );
        });  
    });
```

and if you want to use id

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
console.log('partie1');
    $('#Btn_MILENG').click(function(){
    console.log('partie2');
           $( "#DIV_DETAIL" ).html('<object data="SomeURL"></object>' );
        });  
    });
```

both will work

Answer (score 0):

Because you add button dynamicaly you should use `on` event. And also if your mean of button is a link, then should add ID to the `a` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    console.log('partie1');
        $(document).on("click", '#Btn_MILENG', function(){
        console.log('partie2');
               $( "#DIV_DETAIL" ).html('<object data="SomeURL"></object>' );
            });  
        });
<a  id="Btn_MILENG" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" role="submit" id="Btn_MILENG" name="Btn_MILENG">Détails</a>
```

Comment: The a tag Id was one of my try , i'm on this since a fex hours now and that why i ask for help :) 
Here i'd just try all the solution given but in Chrome , i see the first console log ( on document ready) but the second who fire on click didn't appear. I'm totally lost ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the id attribute in Button element

`<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" role="submit" name="Btn_MILENG" id="Btn_MILENG">Détails</a>`

Answer (score 0):

in The body :

```
                    <ul>                
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="//dbquery[@id='Analyse_Global']/rows/row" group-by="@bde">
                            <xsl:variable name="BDE" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="BDE_Percent" select="round(sum(//dbquery[@id='Analyse_Global']/rows/row[@bde=$BDE]/@OpsPercent) div count(//dbquery[@id='Analyse_Global']/rows/row[@bde=$BDE]))"/>
                        <li>

                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/><br/><xsl:value-of select="concat($BDE_Percent,' %')"/>
                            <br/>

                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#" role="submit">
                            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat('Btn_',current-grouping-key())"/></xsl:attribute>Détails</a>
```

in the head :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//dbquery[@id='Analyse_Global']/rows/row" group-by="@bde">
    <xsl:variable name="BDE" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    <script>      
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
console.log('partie1');
    $(document).on("click", '#Btn_<xsl:value-of select="$BDE"/>', function(){
    console.log('partie2');
           $( "#DIV_DETAIL" ).html('<object data="http://opsnode.mil.intra/LRF/XMLWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/OPSNODE/LCC_STUURBOARD/LCC_STUURBOARD_DETAIL.xml?pRID=100118&amp;pLANG=FR&amp;pBde={$BDE}"></object>' );
        });  
    });
</script>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, but not the solution ... I generate a UL LI dynamically, by then tre JS from caprica orgchart, generate a table to draw a orgchart ... i think that all this stuff dynamically generate did'nt trigger the click function ... i dont how to listen the correct element and which is the correct...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

the JS who create the orgchart, put a "< a> " to have is td clickable... and i try to put a < a> in it , when i finnaly see it , i put my second < a> into a span and this solved the problem. Tks to all !